# Matplotlib, matshow not aligned with gridspec when fig size bi

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to use gridspec to plot multiple types of plots together. I use it with Jupyter Notebook, I realise that when the figure width is bigger than the cell width. The matshow shrunk and no longer aligned with others.

For example, when figsize's width is smaller than the cell width, everything is fine.  .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as grd
duration = 1
data1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0, duration, 10000))
data2 = np.random.random((100,12))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 5], constrained_layout=True)
grid = grd.GridSpec(2, 2, figure=fig, height_ratios=[1, 1], width_ratios=[40, 1])


ax = plt.subplot(grid[0])
ax.plot(data1)

ax = plt.subplot(grid[2])
im = ax.matshow(data2.T, cmap=plt.get_cmap('inferno'), origin='lower')

ax = plt.subplot(grid[3])
cb = plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax)
```

[image]

Then when the width is bigger than the cell. .

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[20, 5], constrained_layout=True)
grid = grd.GridSpec(2, 2, figure=fig, height_ratios=[1, 1], width_ratios=[40, 1])


ax = plt.subplot(grid[0])
ax.plot(data1)

ax = plt.subplot(grid[2])
im = ax.matshow(data2.T, cmap=plt.get_cmap('inferno'), origin='lower')

ax = plt.subplot(grid[3])
cb = plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax)
```

[image]

What is causing the matshow() to shrink and how can I fix it? I am on Python 3.7 with Matplotlib 3.1.3

Thanks

Comment: The aspect ratio of `matshow` is fixed.  If you widen the figure, the matshow will not necessarily get wider because it is a fixed aspect ratio and the height is the constraining dimension.

Comment: Also, you should not need to do the gridspec trick for colorbars if you are able to use constrained_layout.

Comment: I solved the problem by setting aspect to 'auto' for matshow. Can you elaborate on the second point about the colorbar? I didn't find another solution to have matshow align with other plots while having the colorbar

Comment: ```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, constrained_layout=True)
pc = ax[0].matshow(np.random.rand(20, 20), aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax[0])
ax[1].plot(np.random.rand(20))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the whole points of constrained_layout is colorbars are dealt with more gracefully.  i.e. you don't need the `width_ratios=[40, 1]` hack.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, constrained_layout=True)
pc = ax[0].matshow(np.random.rand(20, 20), aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax[0])
ax[1].plot(np.random.rand(20))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i'm tried your code.
If you use plt.show() and maximizes the window:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f9Qd.png)

Comment: Hi, I realised the problem is the width of the figure. I am using Jupyter. When the width is greater than the cell width, the problem occurs. I rephrased the question. So I think you won't see the problem with plt.show() and pop-up window.